# What is an Invalid Ciphertext Header?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I'm using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ciphersweet for database row encryption in a Laravel 10 project. I believe I've implemented it as instructed (my use case is very basic), and am using it to insert a set of rows pulled from an API.

I'm getting an 'Invalid Ciphertext Header' exception when the import hits this line

`$record = (new $model())->newQueryWithoutRelationships()->where('master_id', $masterId)->first();`

I can't find any explanation of what this error means.

I have a CIPHERSWEET_KEY value set in my .env file, that was generated by the artisan command that comes with the package.

My model class looks like this

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Spatie\LaravelCipherSweet\Contracts\CipherSweetEncrypted;
use Spatie\LaravelCipherSweet\Concerns\UsesCipherSweet;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\BlindIndex;

class ClientAccount extends Model implements CipherSweetEncrypted
{
    use HasFactory;

    use UsesCipherSweet;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];

    public static function configureCipherSweet(EncryptedRow $encryptedRow): void
    {
        $encryptedRow
            ->addField('title')
            ->addBlindIndex('title', new BlindIndex('title_index'));
    }

}
```

I have published the ciphersweet config, and it looks to the env value as key provider

`'provider' => env('CIPHERSWEET_PROVIDER', 'string'),`

Any ideas? Can anyone tell me what the ciphertext header is, and how to make it valid?